# Antd Select restore/keep old value and not update with new selected option

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, antd

I have an antd form which has a select component as form item. Something like this:

```
        <Form.Item label='Client Name'>
        {
          getFieldDecorator('clientId', {
            rules: [{
              required: true,
              message: 'Please select client!',
            }],
            initialValue: this.state.clientId
          })(
            <Select
              showSearch
              loading={this.props.isClientLoading}
              optionFilterProp='title'
              style={formItemStyle}
              placeholder='Select Client'
              onChange={this.handleClientChange}
            >
              {this.props.clientOptions}
            </Select>
          )
        }
```

I am maintaining a state for `clientId`. Whenever user selects an option from select dropdown, I update the state value in method `handleClientChange`. But, in one condition, I don't want to update the state value and in that case dropdown selection should also not change. But the thing is `select` calls `handleClientChange` method and then updates the dropdown field. My `handleClientChange` code looks something like this:

```
  handleClientChange = async (selectedClientId: any) => {
    if (this.state.isSomethingChanged) {
      debugger;
/*       setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.form.setFieldsValue({ clientId: this.state.clientId});
      }, 100); */
      this.props.form.setFieldsValue({ clientId: this.state.clientId});
```

As you can see, I tried to update props form value but it updates for a fraction of second and then `select` internally fires the new value and changes it.

As you can also see, I tried a work around of setting a timeout and it works but that is a very unpleasant UX. Can someone help me in restoring the old value of dropdown?

P.S. : I tried setting `value` prop of `select` component but that doesn't work when it is wrapped in `getFieldDecorator`. Antd takes care of making it a controlled component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want a particular option to be selected:

1. Do not create an option for it
2. Make is disabled so that it cannot be selected